# CDbl() Vs Val() in reading double values from a text box

Tags: vb.net

I have a `TextBox` named `ValueText`. when i execute the following code:

```
  Dim txtval As Double = 0.0
  txtval = Val(ValueText.Text)
  txtval = CDbl(ValueText.Text)
```

Both `Val()` and `CDbl()` will do the same work. then what is the difference between these two? where to use  `Val()` and  where to use `CDbl()`

Comment: 'Val' is not a casting function - it will do a lot of work to try to interpret the argument as a number.  'CDbl' expects that the argument is a number already.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the [val()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7beh1x9(v=vs.90).aspx) Returns the numbers contained in a string as a numeric value of appropriate type. where as [CDbl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftekwwt0(v=vs.84).aspx) will Returns an expression that has been converted to a Variant of subtype Double.

The main difference in its use is that

`CDbl()` will return **Error** as `Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.` when The `TextBox` is blank or `Empty`.

While `Val()` will give `0.0` in the above situation

Comment: "converted to a Variant of subtype Double." What??? How about .TryParse

Answer (score 4):

Two subtle differences between the functions:

CDbl("") throws a RTE13 "Type Mismatch" error on a blank/empty string where Val("") returns 0.

CDbl() allows commas as the thousands separator in strings where Val() does not.  i.e. CDbl("-1,234.56") = -1234.56 but Val("-1,234.56") = -1